# ¿como podria comparar los valores pares de un array con los impares del mismo?

Tags: c++, array, comparaciones

Como dice la pregunta tengo que comparar los valores pares e impares y  si todo número que está en una casilla par es mayor que cualquiera de los números que están en las casillas impares mostrar un mensaje que diga "partidario" y "No partidario" en caso contrario.

Se me ocurrió utilizar como base una parte del método burbuja pero no resulto como esperaba.
utilice como ejemplo algo simple, poniendo 100 en los pares y 1 en los impares.

**Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A[10],v,t;
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores del arreglo"<<endl;
    cin>>v;
    }
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(A[i] > A[i+1]){
                cout<<"Partidario!!!"<<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"No partidario!!!"<<endl;
            }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Probablemente este afrontando el problema desde un angulo erróneo pero no se me ocurre otra manera, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Supongo que con la frase: *sí todos los valores pares son mayores que...* se refiere a la suma de los mismos, no a la comparación individual de unos (pares) con otros (impares). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu respuesta, seguramente eso es lo que ignoraba. (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que en cada iteración debes comparar el valor impar con el par, debes incrementar `i` de dos en dos, no de uno en uno:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2)
```

De esta forma `A[i]` **siempre** será un elemento par y `A[i+1]` será un elemento impar

Por otro lado, el mensaje no deberías mostrarlo, entiendo, hasta no saber si todos los elementos del array cumplen con la condición. Tu estás mostrando un mensaje por cada pareja de valores.

```
bool partidario = true;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    partidario &= (A[i] > A[i+1]);
}

if (partidario)
{
    cout<<"Partidario!!!"<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"No partidario!!!"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa un bucle con dos apuntadores:

```
for (int *par = A, impar = A + 1, fin = A + 10; par != fin; par += 2, impar += 2)
{
   // Hacer cosas...
}
```

Pongámoslo en una función:

```
template <typename T, int TAMANYO>
bool es_partidario(const T (&datos)[TAMANYO])
{
    static_assert((TAMANYO % 2) == 0, "Tamanyo debe ser par");

    for (int *par = datos, impar = datos + 1, fin = datos + TAMANYO; par != fin; par += 2, impar += 2)
    {
        if (*par < *impar)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Puedes usarla así:

```
int main()
{
    int A[] {2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5};
    int B[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    int C[] {1, 3, 4};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << es_partidario(A) << '\n'; // Muestra true
    std::cout << es_partidario(B) << '\n';                   // Muestra false
    std::cout << es_partidario(C);                           // No compila

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFNb8IwDIbPza/wmDZa6MTX2AdtkQrnbRcuE0MotOkWqU2qJj0gxG/vnFAk2GE3@/UTv46dlOVDklPx3TS3XCR5nTIIuVS6YrSYE6JZUeZUo6j3JRO0YLDygQsNq/gtfv/8mJOdlDkwtS1ppXlKKy7dRAqFBLj3KdVSeesW3njkQBylqebJlirFKu26bQ3uYOxBFMHQh86KFlTsJaRsxwAxwOYdLyDEyWQFbX8zRQ8LEIG18aHHi4sc@jBCLePiQmndAtMRbiLA6inuRzDGnxXn2CMOzurwDFxrErbdUXecium6EpDRXLGAOEccrJV0VaOCgpmuoFy49s8mi9cbOKAHDjXxjdmjDaY2eMLgGJzAhQFHFpnY4tTWn3148eHVh@EZXLagoY5mO0qns1kiaw1hCDYx16F5@UONcn2l2DNa90t0gz8vr7nFJTcY/EMu7YnaTQxxDU3zCw)</kbd>.